# How can I add int values to a c# array

Tags: c#

I have an array `numArray` with the length set to a value the user can put in. if `arrayLength` is 5 for example I want the for loop to count up by 1 to 5 [1,2,3,4,5]. My error is `numArray[i] = sum + 1;` (System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.')

```
int[] numArray = new int[arrayLength];

int sum = 0;
   
for (int i = 0; i <= arrayLength; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    numArray[i] = sum + 1;
}
```

Comment: in C# arrays are 0 based - you have to enumerate from 0,1,2,3,4  - 5 is not part of the array - that's why you get the out of bound error

Comment: You want `for (int i = 0; i < numArray.Length; i++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `i < arrayLength`.

If `i <= arrayLength` at the last iteration `i = 5` and you try to access `numArray[5]` which does not exists (you have only 5 indexes: 0 to 4 ).

Comment: Thank you very much this fixed the issue